# Using ReactJS how do rows with input text fields maintain state after being sorted

Tags: reactjs

Using ReactJS:

I have a container with six rows. Each row has a product name and an input text field. If I enter a quantity into the input text field and then sort the list (ie A-Z, or Z-A) the input text fields are cleared. I've created an example of my problem on codepen.

How can I sort the rows and have the input text fields keep their value?

https://codepen.io/_d_v_/pen/brXQqQ

```
class Row extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { inputValue: '' }
  }

  handleInputChange(e) {
    this.setState({ inputValue: e.target.value });
  }

  render() {
        return (<div className='row'>
                            <span className='product-name'>{this.props.placeholder}</span>
                      <input type='text' className='row__input-field' value={this.state.inputValue} onChange={ e => this.handleInputChange(e) } />
                        </div>);
  }
}

class Container extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
        this.state = {products: [{name: 'Orange'}, {name: 'Lemon'}, {name: 'Apple'}, {name: 'Pear'}, {name: 'Banana'}, {name: 'Tangerine'}, {name: 'Lime'}]};
  }

    handleSelect(e) {
        const sortedData = getSortedDataByIndexType(this.state.products, Number(e.target.value));
        this.setState({ products: sortedData })
    }

  render() {
        return (<div className='row-container'>
                <select className='sort' onChange={e => this.handleSelect(e)}>
                    <option value="" selected disabled>Sort list options</option>
                    <option value='1'>A-Z</option>
                    <option value='2'>Z-A</option>
                </select>
        {
          this.state.products.map((product, index) => {
            return <Row key={ Math.random() } placeholder={this.state.products[index].name} />
          })
        }
    </div>);
  }
}

const sortArrayByKey = (products, key) => {
  products.sort((a, b) => {
    // ignore upper and lowercase;
    let valueA = a[key].toUpperCase();
    let valueB = b[key].toUpperCase();    
    if (valueA < valueB) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (valueA > valueB) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  });
  return products;
};

const getSortedDataByIndexType = (products, sortKey) => {
  switch (sortKey) {
    case 1:
      products = sortArrayByKey(products, 'name');
      break;
    case 2:
      products = sortArrayByKey(products, 'name');
      products.reverse();
      break;
    default:
      console.log('sort value not handled');
      break;
  }
  return products;
};

ReactDOM.render(<Container />,document.getElementById('container'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By keeping the same `key` of `Row` element on every render will keep the state of corresponding element safe. So change

```
this.state.products.map((product, index) => {
            return <Row key={ Math.random() } placeholder={this.state.products[index].name} />
          })
```

to this

```
this.state.products.map((product, index) => {
            return <Row key={ this.state.products[index].name } placeholder={this.state.products[index].name} />
          })
```

Comment: Prakash, you sir, are a star, thank you very much :-)